# How To Make Label And Values Of Same Height In Bootstrap Radio Button Group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap radio button group, where the label height differs from that of the values.

```css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon-title">Type</span>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="one"> One
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="two"> Two
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="three"> Three
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="four"> Four
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How can I change it so that there is no gap in heights of the label and values?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use .btn-lg class for the labels like in the example.

```css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="addon-title">Type</span>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="one"> One
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="two"> Two
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="three"> Three
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
            <input type="radio" name="eventType" value="four"> Four
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```